# Understanding May's proof of van Kampen when $\mathscr O$ is infinite

Tags: algebraic-topology, proof-explanation, set-theory

I am reading May's proof of the van Kampen theorem (fundamental group version) for the case when $\mathscr O$ is infinite. I don't understand how he concludes that $\operatorname{colim}_{\mathscr S\in \mathscr F} \pi_1(U_{\mathscr S} , x) \cong \pi_1(X, x)$. He writes:

> In fact, by the usual subdivision argument, any loop $I\to X$ and any equivalence $h \colon I \times I \to X$ between loops has **image in some $U_{\mathscr S}$**. This **implies directly** that $\pi_1(X, x)$, together with the homomorphisms $\pi_1(U_{\mathscr S}, x)\to \pi_1(X, x)$, has the universal property that characterizes the claimed colimit.

(Let me know if I should reproduce the entire proof up till this point.)

I don't understand the above on two fronts which are bolded out (in the same order as I ask below):

1. <s>I understand that the image will be in some finite union of $U$'s from $\mathscr O$, but what is the guarantee that any finitely many $U$'s are always contained in some $\mathscr{S\in F}$? Thus we have a set-theoretic question: Is the [$\pi$-system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pi-system) generated by a finite set, finite?</s> [This has been answered by Chris Eagle in his comment.]
2. How? I must be overlooking something very obvious since it is "directly" implied.

Can someone please help?

Comment: I don't have the background to answer most of this question, but your set-theoretic question has a positive answer.  The $\pi$-system generated by a family $F$ is just the set of all finite intersections of members of $F$, that is, it is $\{\cap_{x \in A} x : A \subseteq F, A \text{ finite}\}$.  When $F$ itself is finite this is also finite.

Comment: @ChrisEagle Oof! How could I be so blind!

Comment: Well, it is indeed true that the usual proof of the SvK theorem would give this colimit isomorphism result if I am correctly interpreting what kind of thing the $U_{\mathscr{J}}$ are. But this just amounts to a proof of SvK in all cases, finite or infinite. The infinite case is not really any different from the finite case, at least, not in the way that Hatcher presents it

Comment: @FShrike $U_{\mathscr S}$ is just $\bigcup\mathscr S$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One can directly check the universal property. Suppose we have compatible homomorphisms $f_S\colon \pi_1(U_S)\to G$. Let $\alpha\colon I\to X$ be a loop at $x$. Then as remarked by May there is some $U_S$ that contains $\alpha$, so to define $f\colon \pi_1(X,x)\to G$ we must put $f(\alpha) = f_S(\alpha)$. This implies uniqueness and it remains to check that $f$ is well-defined. Suppose that $\beta$ is path homomotopic to $\alpha$ via $h\colon I\times I\to X$. Then $h$ is contained in $U_T$ for some $T$ such that $U_T$ contains $U_S$. Then $$f(\alpha) = f_S(\alpha) = f_T(\alpha) = f_T(\beta) = f(\beta).$$
The first and last equality are by definition, the second by naturality and the third by the fact that both $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are elements of $\pi_1(U_T,x)$.